# Subtracting a number for each element in a column

Tags: python, numpy

I have a csv file where I can access one of the columns. For instance I have:

```
A
2.5
3.5
4.5
5.5
```

etc.

What I want to do is to subtract all the entries in A by 1.0 for it to become:

```
B
1.5
2.5
3.5
4.5
```

Any ideas on how I can do it? I tried numpy.subtract() but it only leads to error.

Comment: Please show your code including the part where you read the CSV file, and the error you get. It's hard to say whether the problem is the data format (CSV reading issue) or the way you use `numpy.subtract`.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a numpy array you can subtract a constant from the array like:

```
>>> A = numpy.array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5])
>>> A-1
array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5])
```

edit: it's called broadcasting, btw http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the decrement/increment opperator

```
A -= 1
```

This works on the whole array. Loops are just to slow if you can do things with numpy arrays and their great broadcasting capabilities. But pay attention, many of the numpy routines don't work on lists because they are not transforming them to arrays. This might be the reason why numpy.substract() didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in-place then you will need a for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(column)):
   column[i] = column[i] - 1.0
```

Comment: You should avoid doing `range(len(column))` as that can lead to off-by-one bugs. You could just do `for i,data in enumerate(column):` to always get it correct.

Comment: I always try to use list comprehension instead of looping if I can help it: `B = [x-1 for x in A]`.

Comment: `for i in column:` will give you the elements of the list, not the indices. At least use enumerate: `for i,x in enumerate(column):`

Answer (score -1):

You can "map" a function across the list using the apply named [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
>>> A = [2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
>>> B = map(lambda x: x-1., A)
>>> B
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
>>>
```

Where `lambda x: x-1` is the anonymous function to which all elements of `A` are applied.  For `2.5` the function returns `2.5-1`, for `3.5` the function returns `3.5-1` and so on.